# Getting the first XML element with SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

ok, this might be a stupid question, but how do I get one single element from an XML document?

I have this XML

```
$element = $response['linkedin'];

SimpleXMLElement Object
( 
    [id] => 575677478478
    [first-name] => John
    [last-name] => Doe
    [email-address] => john@doe.com
    [picture-url] => http://m3.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/123
    [headline] => Headline goes here
    [industry] => Internet
    [num-connections] => 71
```

I just want to assign `first-name` as `$firstName`

I can loop over it using xPath, but that just seems like overkill.

ex:

```
$fName = $element->xpath('first-name');
foreach ($fName as $name) 
{
    $firstName = $name;
}
```

Comment: If that `XMLElement` is the the only thing you are working with in the `$response['linkedin']`, `$response[linkedin']->{'first-name'} = $name`; should be able to do it for you.

Comment: Thanks @Jon, that's what I was looking for! If you add this as an answer I'll accept.

Comment: Please also make use of the exisitng documentation which shows this and much more: http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer form per request. ^^

If that `SimpleXMLElement` is the only one contained within `$resource['linkedin']`, you can change it with:

```
$resource['linkedin']->{'first-name'} = $name;
```

That allows you direct access to the element without needing to do an `xpath` on it. ^^

Answer (score 3):

If you access a list of (one or more) element nodes in SimpleXML as a single element, it will return the first element. That is by default (and outlined as well in the [SimpleXML Basic Usage](http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic)):

```
$first = $element->{'first-name'};
```

If there are more than one element, you can specify which one you mean by using the zero-based index of it, either in square (array-access) or curly (property-access) brackets:

```
$first = $element->{'first-name'}[0];
$first = $element->{'first-name'}{0};
```

This also allows you to create a so called SimpleXML self-reference to access the element itself, e.g. to remove it:

```
unset($first[0]);  # removes the element node from the document.

unset($first);     # unsets the variable $first
```

You might think your Xpath would be overkill. But it's not that expensive in SimpleXML. Sometimes the only way to access an element is *with* Xpath even. Therefore it might be useful for you to know that you can easily access the first element as well per an xpath. For example the parent element in SimpleXML:

```
list($parent) $element->xpath('..'); # PHP < 5.4

$parent = $element->xpath('..')[0];  # PHP >= 5.4
```

As you can see it is worth to actually understand how things work to make more use of SimpleXML. If you already know all from the *SimpleXML Basic Usage* page, you might want to learn a bit more with the

- [*SimpleXML Type Cheatsheet*](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2013/02/12/simplexml-type-cheatsheet/)
- [*How to tell apart SimpleXML objects representing element and attribute?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14829309/367456)
- [*SimpleXMLElement implements JsonSerializable*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16093864/367456)

Comment: "_If you access a list of (one or more) element nodes in SimpleXML as a single element, it will return the first element_" - I am confused by this one. If I had an xml string with 2 parents and each parent had 5 children, why does `$xml->parent->count()` return 2 and `$xml->parent[0]->count()` return 5? Both $xml->parent and $xml->parent[0] seem to point to the same first parent element.

Comment: Yeah it is confusing, to answer your question: That is b/c `$xml->parent->count()`  counts the child-elements named *parent* of the `$xml`  element, while `$xml->parent[0]->count()` counts all child elements of the first child element named *parent* from the `$xml` element. /// `$xml->parent` and `$xml->parent[0]` never point to the same object b/c the
first is a list of child elements named *parent* and the second is the first
child element named *parent*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath to find the first instance of a matching element.

/root/firstname[1] would give you the first instance of firstname in your document.

```
$res=$response['linkedin']->xpath('/first-name[1]');
```

Comment: That still returns an Array

Comment: Should be an array with one element though -- just take the first one.